# Scroll to fix issue with scrolling up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm facing a problem with the scroll to fixed on big articles. The plugin can be found here: https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed. The case is that I wan't some article numbers fixed at the top of the articles. When I scroll down, the number has to scroll up when the next article is reached. The way down goes very well, no gaps or numbers over eachother. But when I'm scrolling up slowly, there is something like a gap in my scroll, the scroll is not normal. When I'm scrolling up very fast, the numbers are over eachother.

My script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Dock each summary as it arrives just below the docked header, pushing the
// previous summary up the page.

    var articleblocknr = $('.gwn_betnr');
    articleblocknr.each(function(i) {
        var block = $(articleblocknr[i]);
        var next = articleblocknr[i + 1];

        block.scrollToFixed({
            //marginTop: $('.header').outerHeight(true) + 10,
            limit: function() {
                var limit = 0;
                if (next) {
                    limit = $(next).offset().top - $(this).outerHeight(true);
                } else {
                    limit = $('.footer').offset().top - $(this).outerHeight(true);
                }
                return limit;
            },
            zIndex: 999
        });
    });
});
```

My page articles:

```
    <li id="gwn_betnr1" class="gwn_betnr">

        <span class="gwn_betnrf">1</span>

    </li>

    <li class="gwn_bet">

        <span class="gwn_def gwn_illus">Definition 1</span>

        <span class="gwn_bet_beh">

            <span class="gwn_regel">

                <span class="gwn_grijs">test1 </span>

                <span class="gwn_steun">test2</span>

            </span>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet. Ut convallis libero in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros. Donec viverra mi quis quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In rutrum accumsan ultricies. Mauris vitae nisi at sem facilisis semper ac in est.</p>

            <p>Vivamus fermentum semper porta. Nunc diam velit, adipiscing ut tristique vitae, sagittis vel odio. Maecenas convallis ullamcorper ultricies. Curabitur ornare, ligula semper consectetur sagittis, nisi diam iaculis velit, id fringilla sem nunc vel mi. Nam dictum, odio nec pretium volutpat, arcu ante placerat erat, non tristique elit urna et turpis. Quisque mi metus, ornare sit amet fermentum et, tincidunt et orci. Fusce eget orci a orci congue vestibulum. Ut dolor diam, elementum et vestibulum eu, porttitor vel elit. Curabitur venenatis pulvinar tellus gravida ornare. Sed et erat faucibus nunc euismod ultricies ut id justo. Nullam cursus suscipit nisi, et ultrices justo sodales nec. Fusce venenatis facilisis lectus ac semper. Aliquam at massa ipsum. Quisque bibendum </p>

        </span>

    </li>

    <li id="gwn_betnr2" class="gwn_betnr">

        <span class="gwn_betnrf">2</span>

    </li>

    <li class="gwn_bet">

        <span class="gwn_def gwn_illus">Definition 2</span>

        <span class="gwn_bet_beh">

            <span class="gwn_regel">

                <span class="gwn_grijs">test1 </span>

                <span class="gwn_steun">test2</span>

            </span>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet. Ut convallis libero in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros. Donec viverra mi quis quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In rutrum accumsan ultricies. Mauris vitae nisi at sem facilisis semper ac in est.</p>

            <p>Vivamus fermentum semper porta. Nunc diam velit, adipiscing ut tristique vitae, sagittis vel odio. Maecenas convallis ullamcorper ultricies. Curabitur ornare, ligula semper consectetur sagittis, nisi diam iaculis velit, id fringilla sem nunc vel mi. Nam dictum, odio nec pretium volutpat, arcu ante placerat erat, non tristique elit urna et turpis. Quisque mi metus, ornare sit amet fermentum et, tincidunt et orci. Fusce eget orci a orci congue vestibulum. Ut dolor diam, elementum et vestibulum eu, porttitor vel elit. Curabitur venenatis pulvinar tellus gravida ornare. Sed et erat faucibus nunc euismod ultricies ut id justo. Nullam cursus suscipit nisi, et ultrices justo sodales nec. Fusce venenatis facilisis lectus ac semper. Aliquam at massa ipsum. Quisque bibendum </p>

        </span>

    </li>

    <li id="gwn_betnr3" class="gwn_betnr">

        <span class="gwn_betnrf">3</span>

    </li>

    <li class="gwn_bet">

        <span class="gwn_def gwn_illus">Definition 3</span>

        <span class="gwn_bet_beh">

            <span class="gwn_regel">

                <span class="gwn_grijs">test1 </span>

                <span class="gwn_steun">test2 </span>

            </span>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet. Ut convallis libero in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros. Donec viverra mi quis quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In rutrum accumsan ultricies. Mauris vitae nisi at sem facilisis semper ac in est.</p>

            <p>Vivamus fermentum semper porta. Nunc diam velit, adipiscing ut tristique vitae, sagittis vel odio. Maecenas convallis ullamcorper ultricies. Curabitur ornare, ligula semper consectetur sagittis, nisi diam iaculis velit, id fringilla sem nunc vel mi. Nam dictum, odio nec pretium volutpat, arcu ante placerat erat, non tristique elit urna et turpis. Quisque mi metus, ornare sit amet fermentum et, tincidunt et orci. Fusce eget orci a orci congue vestibulum. Ut dolor diam, elementum et vestibulum eu, porttitor vel elit. Curabitur venenatis pulvinar tellus gravida ornare. Sed et erat faucibus nunc euismod ultricies ut id justo. Nullam cursus suscipit nisi, et ultrices justo sodales nec. Fusce venenatis facilisis lectus ac semper. Aliquam at massa ipsum. Quisque bibendum </p>

        </span>

    </li>

    <li id="gwn_betnr4" class="gwn_betnr">

        <span class="gwn_betnrf">4</span>

    </li>

    <li class="gwn_bet">

        <span class="gwn_def gwn_illus">Definition 4</span>

        <span class="gwn_bet_beh">

            <span class="gwn_regel">

                <span class="gwn_grijs">test1 </span>

                <span class="gwn_steun">test2 </span>

            </span>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet. Ut convallis libero in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros. Donec viverra mi quis quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In rutrum accumsan ultricies. Mauris vitae nisi at sem facilisis semper ac in est.</p>

            <p>Vivamus fermentum semper porta. Nunc diam velit, adipiscing ut tristique vitae, sagittis vel odio. Maecenas convallis ullamcorper ultricies. Curabitur ornare, ligula semper consectetur sagittis, nisi diam iaculis velit, id fringilla sem nunc vel mi. Nam dictum, odio nec pretium volutpat, arcu ante placerat erat, non tristique elit urna et turpis. Quisque mi metus, ornare sit amet fermentum et, tincidunt et orci. Fusce eget orci a orci congue vestibulum. Ut dolor diam, elementum et vestibulum eu, porttitor vel elit. Curabitur venenatis pulvinar tellus gravida ornare. Sed et erat faucibus nunc euismod ultricies ut id justo. Nullam cursus suscipit nisi, et ultrices justo sodales nec. Fusce venenatis facilisis lectus ac semper. Aliquam at massa ipsum. Quisque bibendum </p>

        </span>

    </li>
<div class="footer">
            ...
</div>
```

My css:

```
body, html { margin:0; padding:0; color:#2a2a2a; background:#fff; } .footer { display: block; background:#f2f2f2; clear: both; } .gwn_romp { list-style: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; } .gwn_betnr { float:left; width:1.250em; height: 2.300em; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; border-top: 1px solid black; /*padding-top: 0.450em;*/ /* 28px - 19px (l2b) = 9px */ overflow: hidden; } .gwn_bet { float: left; margin-left: 1.400em; } .gwn_def { display: block; color: #000; } .gwn_bet_beh { display: block; } .gwn_regel { display: block; /* clear: both; */ }
```

Can somebody help me with this problem? I've made a fiddle as well, scrolling down works fine, scrolling up is on the switch with the numbers not smooth. https://jsfiddle.net/45ab7pka/4/

Comment: Odd, works fine on Firefox but I see the issue on other browsers.

Comment: I see the flipping also in Firefox. Between number 1 and 2 everything works fine. Scrolling up and down. But when I'm between 2 and opening 3. Then very slowly scroll up, it flips the scroll a little. When I scroll fast, the numbers go over each other.

Comment: Yes, I notice it now. That little jump only happens with the first number it meets when going up. But let's see what the answer provides...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() { console.log('test');
    // Dock each summary as it arrives just below the docked header, pushing the
    // previous summary up the page.

    var articleblocknr = $('.gwn_betnr');
    articleblocknr.each(function(i) {
        var block = $(articleblocknr[i]);
        var next = articleblocknr[i + 1];

        block.scrollToFixed({
            //marginTop: $('.header').outerHeight(true) + 10,
            limit: function() {
                var limit = 0;
                if (next) {
                    5 = $(next).offset().top - $(this).outerHeight(true);
                } else {
                    limit = $('.footer').offset().top - $(this).outerHeight(true);
                }
                return limit;
            },
            zIndex: 999
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The only change I see is that you've changed "limit" to "5"? Nothing has changed in the else-statement? So same bug is in the fiddle with this code.